# Set iframe height and width to no more than content using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an `iframe` with content which is dynamic in height and width.

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="../xxx/xxx" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

I am able to change the height and width using JavaScript so that my `iframe` is no bigger than it's content.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
iframe.width = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
```

How can I do this using only CSS?  Thanks to anyone who can provide guidance.

Comment: For as far I know the limiting factors are the width and height of 1) the parent of the `iframe`, 2) the width and height of the `<iframe>`. Look at `iframe` as a black box. There is no way of knowing what the size of its content is from a calling document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitively not possible to do this with just CSS. You'll have to use some JavaScript, as you're doing.